# Cocoa multi window drag and drop example

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, multi-window

I am looking for a cocoa example that illustrates how to drag an image from one window to another.  If not I would like to see an example that shows dragging an image from a source and destination in the same window.  If anyone has a link to any such examples I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Searching for "drag and drop" on [Apple's sample code page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+Code) gives:

- http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/CocoaDragAndDrop/index.html
- http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/DragAndDrop_Shell/index.html
- http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/DragItemAround/index.html
- http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/DragNDropOutlineView/index.html