# NSTableView drag cell to NSView

Tags: drag, nstableview, nsview

Could someone nudge me in the right direction on this. I want to drag a NSString from a table cell to a NSView and then do something based on that string but the drag and drop stuff has my head spinning a bit. Anyway know of a straight forward tutorial that can explain all this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The table view data source has a method for starting a drag operation. Here's a little code to start the dragging:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pboard
{
    NSString *myString = ...; // code to get a string from the indexes in rowIndexes
    return [pboard setString:myString forType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
}
```

For receiving drag operations, I think there has been enough written about it:
This is an older tutorial (2002), but I think it should still be valid. Just be sure to check the documentation about deprecated methods/names (or look at the compiler warnings): http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000056.php

[Apples drag and drop programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Concepts/dragdestination.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000977-BAJBJFBG)

Or this stack overflow question with links to sample code: [Cocoa multi window drag and drop example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457846/cocoa-multi-window-drag-and-drop-example)